# Showing Zero Values in Pivot Table in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I have an unremarkable pivot table in a completely new workbook.  I tried both "For empty cells show 0" in pivot table options and "show blank values" in field settings to no avail.  Is there another method to force Excel to show items with value 0?

For example, [this tutorial](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/pivottbls/empty_cells2013.php) doesn't work for me at all.

Comment: What is it showing now? What kind of data is being summarized and how?

Comment: @Excellll Numerical data on the left and the counts of those numbers on the right.